# How to use lambda function as hash function in unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wonder if it is possible to use lambda function as custom hash function for unordered_map in C++11? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: What have you tried? Just need to pass the lambda, or a variable that holds a lambda

Comment: @Ajay, I tried, but some weird errors always occurs...now I know how to do it...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

int main() {
    auto my_hash = [](std::string const& foo) {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(foo);
    };

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int, decltype(my_hash)> my_map(10, my_hash); 
}
```

You need to pass lambda object to `unordered_map` constructor, since lambda types are not default constructible.

As @mmocny suggested in comment, it's also possible to define make function to enable type deduction if you really want to get rid of `decltype`:

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

template<
        class Key,
        class T,
        class Hash = std::hash<Key>
        // skipped EqualTo and Allocator for simplicity
>
std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash> make_unordered_map(
        typename std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash>::size_type bucket_count = 10,
        const Hash& hash = Hash()) {
    return std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash>(bucket_count, hash);
}

int main() {
    auto my_map = make_unordered_map<std::string, int>(10,
            [](std::string const& foo) {
                return std::hash<std::string>()(foo);
            });
}
```

Comment: Or, write a make_unordered_hash templated function for type deduction.  There is also actually a C++ proposal to more generally address this problem http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3602.html