# Is it possible to use a lambda function for a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was looking at std::unordered_map and saw that if I wanted to use a string as the key, I'd have to create a class containing a functor.

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if a lambda could be used in place of this.

Here's the working original:

```
struct hf
{
  size_t operator()(string const& key) const
  {
    return key[0];  // some bogus simplistic hash. :)
  }
}

std::unordered_map<string const, int, hf> m = {{ "a", 1 }};
```

Here's my attempt:

```
std::unordered_map<string const, int, [](string const& key) ->size_t {return key[0];}> m = {{ "a", 1 }};
```

That failed with the following errors:

```
exec.cpp: In lambda function:
exec.cpp:44:77: error: ‘key’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
exec.cpp:44:82: error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression
exec.cpp: At global scope:
exec.cpp:44:86: error: template argument 3 is invalid
exec.cpp:44:90: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
exec.cpp:44:102: error: braces around scalar initializer for type ‘int’
```

Given the errors, it would seem that the lamba is different enough from a functor that it makes it not a constant expression.  Is that correct?

Comment: `std::hash` is specialized for `std::string`, no need to provide something yourself if you don't want to improve / change the hash. Also, think about what you're doing: `std::unordered_map` expects a *type* as the template argument, and a lambda expression is exactly that - an expression, i.e., a value, *not* a type.

Comment: I found that in the g++ compiler I was using (v4.5.3 with -std=gnu++0x), it would give me a bunch of errors if I didn't specify the hash function when using a string key.

Comment: As for it being an expression, yeah, I guess that would be the answer.

Comment: Actually, hold on.  Although it's an 'expression' is it not more like a function?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719084/how-to-use-lambda-function-as-hash-function-in-unordered-map/15719698#15719698

Comment: 4.5.3 supports very little of C++11. Don't use this combination for anything serious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to pass the lambda function is:

```
auto hf = [](string const& key)->size_t { return key[0]; };

unordered_map<string const, int, decltype(hf)> m (1, hf);
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^
                                 passing type        object
```

The output of `decltype(hf)` is a class type which doesn't have default constructor (it's deleted by `=delete`). So, you need pass the object by constructor of `unordered_map` to let it construct the lambda object.

Comment: @MM., like this: `std::unordered_map<string const, int, decltype(hf)> m(1, hf);`. The first argument is the initial bucket count, the second is the hasher. You can't use brace-initialization in this case, sadly.

Comment: Interesting, though kinda cheating as you are not just passing the lambda function as a template parameter. In fact, the template parameter can be avoided all together via a helper template function like: `template<class HASHER> auto make_unordered_map(size_t bucketCount, HASHER const & hf) -> unordered_map<string const, int, decltype(hf)> { return unordered_map<string const, int, decltype(hf)>(bucketCount, hf); }` as seen [here](http://ideone.com/62heUn). Still, it is interesting. :)