# Can I use lambda as a hashing function in boost::multi_index hash-like interface?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Is it possible to use lambda for hashing in [hashed_<non>_unique](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#hash_spec) interface for boost::multi_index?
See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/1voof3

I also saw this: [How to use lambda function as hash function in unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719084/how-to-use-lambda-function-as-hash-function-in-unordered-map) where the answer says:

> You need to pass lambda object to unordered_map constructor since lambda types are not default constructible.

and I'm not sure is it even possible to do for the given example on godbolt.

Comment: The current C++ standard is, of course, C++20 which allows default constructed lambdas. That is, something like this is legal: `std::unordered_set<int, decltype([](auto x){ return hash(x); })> s;`

Comment: Not an answer, but it [is possible](https://web.archive.org/web/20240307155418/https://boost-users.boost.narkive.com/h9X49Ul3/multiindex-key-extractor-as-free-function-how) to use a free function to extract a key, pre C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with C++20, yes, you can: https://godbolt.org/z/fTbzPP (note `f` is declared as `auto const hash_f`, without a `&`).

As for @sehe's claim that `multi_index_container`s can't be passed instances of hash objects (or other intervening function objects) at construction time, the claim is incorrect: they can, although the interface is somewhat complicated:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24df790bd350e085)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <functional>

struct non_default_ctble_hash
{
  non_default_ctble_hash(std::size_t n):n{n}{}
  
  template<typename T>
  std::size_t operator()(const T& x){return std::hash<T>{}(x)*n;}

  std::size_t n;
};

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using container=multi_index_container<
  int,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique<identity<int>,non_default_ctble_hash>
  >
>;

int main()
{
  container::ctor_args_list cal{
    {0,identity<int>{},non_default_ctble_hash{666},std::equal_to<int>{}}
  };
  
  container c(cal);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. :) I'm still trying to demystify [ctor_args_list](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/creation.html#ctor_args_list). I can't get it to work using `tag` instead of `uint index` as the first argument:[link](https://godbolt.org/z/Gda7Ys).

Comment: Have I misread the documentation stating that it isn't supported? (Alternattively, where is this documented?)

Comment: Indices are indeed not constructible on their own: one can only get a *reference* to an index from a previously existing `multi_index_container`. Docs for `ctor_args_list`: https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/creation.html#ctor_args_list

Comment: @Daniel the `0` you see in `{0,identity<int>{},...` is not the index number, but the first configuration parameter of hashed indices (number of buckets). You can't specify which indices you provide construction objects for in  `ctor_args_list`, but instead you have to supply as many tuples as there are indices, in their definition order.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. With a standard container you would have had to supply the actual instance to the constructor. However, MultiIndex doesn't afford that:

**[docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#constructors)**

> As explained in the [index concepts section](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/indices.html#index_concepts), indices do not have public constructors or destructors. Assignment, on the other hand, is provided. Upon construction, max_load_factor() is 1.0.

### Loophole?

You can perhaps get away with a locally defined class:

```
auto const hash_f = [](int const& n) { return std::hash<int>()(n); };
struct HashType : decltype(hash_f) {};

using AnimalsMultiIndex = multi_index_container<
    Animal, indexed_by<hashed_non_unique<
                tag<animal_legs>, member<Animal, LegsType, &Animal::legs>,
                HashType>>>;

AnimalsMultiIndex animals;
```

Which does work: [c++20 required](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a03d358c38abf543)

```
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using LegsType = int;

struct Animal {
    std::string name;
    LegsType legs;
};

// tags
struct animal_legs {};

int main() {
    // using lambda doesn't work for hashing
    auto const hash_f = [](int const& n) { return std::hash<int>()(n); };
    struct HashType : decltype(hash_f) {};

    using AnimalsMultiIndex = multi_index_container<
        Animal, indexed_by<hashed_non_unique<
                    tag<animal_legs>, member<Animal, LegsType, &Animal::legs>,
                    HashType>>>;

    AnimalsMultiIndex animals;

    animals.insert({ "cat", 4 });

    auto const& legs_index = animals.get<animal_legs>();
    int num_of_legs = 4;
    std::cout << "Number of animals that have " << num_of_legs
              << " legs is: " << legs_index.count(num_of_legs) << '\n';
}
```

Prints

```
Number of animals that have 4 legs is: 1
```

Comment: I didn't know about `struct HashType : decltype(hash_f) {};`. Thanks :)